# Save XML-file remotely to server using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a scrip that runs and saves text to an XML-file. And I want to save this XML-file to a remote server in the network. What would be the command/code to to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UNC path (\\server\share\file.xml or \\server\c$\temp\file.xml). It requires the user who runs the script has to have permissions on the target location on the remote server.